# Creating Dataframe in python, passing it as parameter to function in R, but the dataframe columns aren't accessable. Using RPy2

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2

The input values in the python function is given below. input_X is converted to dict with the keys stored as "0" and "1" with each iteration (to be accessed in R).

```
Y = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
input_X = [[3,4,3,4,3,1,5,4,6,7,5,3], [4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,8,7,8,7]]
X = {}
    for i in range(len(input_X)):
        X[str(i)]=input_X[i]
```

X changed to R Dataframe:

```
RX = robjects.DataFrame(X)
```

It calls R function:

```
    r('''
           source('r_test.r')
    ''')
    r_getname = robjects.globalenv['logistic_regression']
    x=r_getname(RY,RX)
    return str(x)
```

Now coming to R:

```
logistic_regression = function(y,x){
    print(x["1"])
}
```

Gives an error that column "1" doesn't exist.
So what's the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.  First, you need to first convert the python arrays to R integer vectors.  E.g.:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

Y = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
input_X = [[3,4,3,4,3,1,5,4,6,7,5,3], [4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,8,7,8,7]]
X = {}
    for i in range(len(input_X)):
        X[str(i)]=robjects.IntVector(input_X[i])

robjects.r('''
logistic_regression = function(x){
    print(colnames(x))
}
''')

xr = robjects.DataFrame(X)
robjects.r.logistic_regression(xr)
```

Second, note that this prints X0 and X1, not 0 and 1, since column names can't start with numbers without check.names=F in the constructor (but this parameter doesn't exist in Rpy2 DataFrame function).